# Regex PHP Only Match if Not Surrounded By Quotes

Tags: php, regex

I have some regex I run over an entire HTML page looking for strings and replacing them, however if the string is in single or double quotes I do not want it to match.

Current Regex: `([a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*)`

I would like to match `steve`,`john`,`cathie` and `john likes to walk` (x3)
but not `"steve"`, `'sophie'` or `"john"'likes'"cake"`

I have tried `(^")([a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*)(^")` but get no matches?

Test Cases:

```
(steve=="john") would return steve
("test"=="test") would not return anything
(boob==lol==cake) would return all three
```

Comment: I looked at your regex again and noticed that `([a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*)` already matches without the quotes...

Comment: @BoltClock The problem is that he only wants it to match when there are no quotes (I think).

Comment: Are these strings as is? Start/finish is `steve`, `john`. Or do they exist in another context, such as `steve went for a walk with john. John said "Steve"`. What are a couple of test cases?

Comment: What is the context...test cases please...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this one:

```
(\b(?<!['"])[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*\b(?!['"]))
```

Against this string:

```
john "michael" michael 'michael elt0n_john 'elt0n_j0hn'
 1      2        3        4       5            6
```

It would match nr 1 `john`, nr 3 `Michael` and nr 5 `elt0n_john`

Answer (score 3):

To do that you probably need some dark magic:

```
'~(?:"[^"\\\\]*+(?:\\\\.[^"\\\\]*+)*+"|\'[^\'\\\\]*+(?:\\\\.[^\'\\\\]*+)*+\')(*SKIP)(*F)|([a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*)~'
```

The `(?:"[^"\\\\]*+(?:\\\\.[^"\\\\]*+)*+"|\'[^\'\\\\]*+(?:\\\\.[^\'\\\\]*+)*+\')` part matches a string in either single or double quotes and implements backslash-escaping. The `(*SKIP)(*F)` skips the quoted string and forces a fail. `([a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*)` is your regex.

PS: If you are using this on PHP scripts, you may want to use the [Tokenizer](http://php.net/Tokenizer) instead. That way you could for example exclude keywords (like `class` or `abstract`, I don't know whether you need this) and you will have much better handling of edge cases (like HEREDOC).

Answer (score 2):

You could try with:

```
preg_match_all('#(?<!["\']) \b \w+ \b (?!["\'])#x', $str, $matches);
```

The `\w+` matches word characters, but would allow `0123sophie` for example. The `\b` matches word boundaries and thus ensures that the anti-quote assertions do not terminate too early.

However, this regex will also fail to find words which have just a single quote "before or after' them.

Comment: Tested and works great in regex coach...fail in PHP though, not sure why. http://codepad.org/LEitQoEJ Could just be codepad's issue.

Comment: just did the same as well. Using the test case I posted in codpad I tried in in the PHP CLI. It works great and returns an array containing `but`, `john`, `like`, `apples`

Answer (score 1):

Pez, resurrecting this ancient question because the current answer is not quite correct (and I'm not sure any solution can be).

It will fail to match `john` when it is in incomplete quotes, for instance in `"john`, `john"`, `'john` and `john'` (situations that can happen with `john's birthday` etc. See [this demo](http://regex101.com/r/bU4gU4).

This alternate solution just skips any content in quotes:

```
(?:'[^'\n]*'|"[^"\n]*")(*SKIP)(*F)|\b[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*\b
```

See [demo](http://regex101.com/r/xX7wD4)

Either way, with quotes, no solution is perfect because you always run the risk of having unbalanced quotes. In this case I have tried to mitigate the problem by assuming that if it's on another line, it's a different string.

**Reference**

1. [How to match pattern except in situations s1, s2, s3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23589174)
2. [How to match a pattern unless...](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html)

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think I have it and it works for your test cases:

```
(?<!"|'|\w)(\w+)(?!"|'|\w)
```

Done with look-ahead/look-behind regex feature.